# C implementation of Assembler code

Tags: c, assembly

I'm trying to rewrite this asm code in C, but my asm knowledge very bad.

```
struct
{
 union
 {
  struct{
  WORD  ShiftZ0;
  WORD  ShiftZ1;
  WORD  ShiftZ2;
  WORD  ShiftZ3; };
  struct{
  DWORD ShiftZ01;
  DWORD ShiftZ23; };
 };
  short ShiftZ0Align;
  short ShiftZ1Align;
  short ShiftZ2Align;
  short ShiftZ3Align;
  int   deltaZ0ToNextLine;
  int   deltaZ1ToNextLine;
  void *Palette;
} AsmDrawData;
```

inline void AsmDrawWithZ16(BYTE *zdata,BYTE *data,WORD *zbuffer,void *video,int no_dot) {
__asm
  {
  cmp     no_dot,0
  je      end
  mov     esi,zdata
  mov     edi,video
  mov     ebx,zbuffer
  mov     ecx,AsmDrawData.Palette
lp:
  mov     eax,AsmDrawData.ShiftZ01
  add     ax,[esi]
  cmp     ax,[ebx]
  jle     end_out_byte
  mov     [ebx],ax
  mov     edx,data
  movzx   edx,byte ptr [edx]
  mov     DX_REG,[ecx+edx*(COLOR_DEPTH/8)]
  mov     [edi],DX_REG
end_out_byte:
  add     edi,(COLOR_DEPTH/8)
  add     ebx,2
  add     esi,2
  inc     data
  dec     no_dot
  jg      lp
end:
  }
}

This is what I write, but this wrong:

```
inline void AsmDrawWithZ16(BYTE *zdata,BYTE *data,WORD *zbuffer,void *video,int no_dot)     {
  for( int i = 0; i < no_dot; i++ ) { 
   if( ((WORD*)zdata)[i] + AsmDrawData.ShiftZ0 >= ((WORD*)zbuffer)[i] )
    {
        ((WORD*)zbuffer)[i] = ((WORD*)zdata)[i] + AsmDrawData.ShiftZ0;
        ((WORD*)video)[i]   = ((WORD*)AsmDrawData.Palette)[((BYTE*)data)[i]];
    }
  }
}
```

Where I could be wrong? (sorry for my very very bad english)

Comment: It would help us to help you if you would also paste some sample data to see precisely how it is wrong. The asm code has an `if` inside the loop which isn't present in your code.

Comment: Hmm. It's very strange that IF statement doesn't exist in my question — in code of my question it is. I add IF, now there are all my function.

Comment: And I'm sorry, but I can't show some sample data — this code for software rendering. It's very easy to see on screen that something wrong, but what exactly — hard. I think that something wrong with Z compare, but I can't understand what exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a real answer.  It's just some ideas and a rewriting of the function as I understand it in hopefully a more clear form.

I highly suspect that your problem was with the line:

```
 if( ((WORD*)zdata)[i] + AsmDrawData.ShiftZ0 >= ((WORD*)zbuffer)[i] )
```

In this code you cast the `zdata` pointer from a *byte* to a *word* pointer.  That seems odd to me.  The assembly does appear to have done the same thing, though.  Since you probably know more about how the *zdata* field gets populated you can probably make a better determination about it.

This zbuffer algorithm appears to be fairly standard, so even without trying to reverse engineer this assembly you should be able to re-implement it in C fairly easily.

I rewrote this, .  I like to keep this localized, so I just declare local pointers at the top that have the correct types (and also use the C99 stdint names because they are more portable than WORD).

```
#include <stdint.h>

inline void AsmDrawWithZ16(BYTE *zdata,BYTE *data,WORD *zbuffer,void *video,int no_dot) {
  uint8_t * zd = zdata;  // Should this be 8 or 16 bit
  uint8_t * dat = data;
  uint16_t * zb = zbuffer;
  uint16_t shz = AsmDrawData.ShiftZ0;
  uint16_t * vid = (uint16_t *)video;

  for( int i = 0; i < no_dot; i++ ) {
    uint16_t X = shz + zd[i];
    if( X >= zb[i] )  // Is this the correct direction of the compare
     {
        zb[i] = zdata[i] + X;  // update the depth
        vid[i] = AsmDrawData.Palette[ dat[i] ]; // update the color
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be correct. I change zd type to uint16_t (because zdata actually 16 bit Z buffer) and almost of rendering good. There is another error with it, but I think that I can fix it. But maybe I can't :)

Comment: I understand what wrong. There are sign/unsigned confusion with some operations. This is correct:

Comment: int16_t * zd = (int16_t *)zdata;
uint8_t * dat = data;
int16_t * zb = (int16_t *)zbuffer;
uint16_t shz = AsmDrawData.ShiftZ0;
uint16_t * vid = (uint16_t *)video;
[...]
int16_t X = shz + zd[i];
[...]
zb[i] = X;  // update the depth